# Gulp file change into a concat stream

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I have a multiple build set up with my gulp file(dev,uat etc) and I need to define certain variables in my app.js file then concat them into my main bundle file.

I dont want to have to create the edited file then concat that file. Is it possible to make the variable change then take the file changed in memory and use that in the concat?

```
gulp.src('_app.js').pipe(replace("'baseURL':", "'baseURL':'www.test.com'"))
            .pipe(concat(['list of files','file in memory']));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`gulp-replace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) to do the actual replacement in your `app.js`, then use [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) to combine it with your other source files:

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var order = require('gulp-order');

gulp.task('concat', function() {
  var appStream = gulp.src('app.js')
    .pipe(replace(/'baseURL':/, "'baseURL':'www.test.com'"));
  return merge(appStream, gulp.src(['list of files']))
    .pipe(order(['app.js', '*.js']))
    .pipe(concat('concatenatedFile.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this I looked at merge but it just didnt make sense to me until put into context. thank you again.

Comment: how do you set the ordering of the merge?

Comment: Check out [`gulp-order`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order). I've updated my answer with an example that puts `app.js` in front of all the other `.js` files.

Comment: I ended up using gulp streamque